# A question about rings, true or false statements

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let R be a ring such that $x^2=x$ for each x in R. Which of the following must be true?

I‐ x= ‐x for all x in R.

II‐ R is commutative

III‐ xy+yx=0 for all x in R

I know that for R to be a ring there are three conditions that must be met. They are:

1)[A,+] is an abelian group (i.e. its commutative)

2)multiplication is associative in A, and

3)multiplication is left and right- distributed over addition.

Therefore I know by definition that II is correct, but need help figuring out if I and III are correct.

Comment: Your belief about II is mistaken, as whoever asked you this probably means that the *multiplication* is commutative, which is not true for rings in general.

Answer (score 1):

If $x\in R$, then
$$2x=(2x)^2 = (x+x)^2 = (x+x)(x+x) = x^2 + x^2 + x^2 + x^2 = 4x^2 = 4x$$
hence $4x=2x$, so $2x=0$.

Thus, $2x=0$, for all $x\in R$.

Equivalently, $x=-x$, for all $x\in R$.

If $x,y\in R$, then
$$x+y = (x+y)^2 = (x+y)(x+y) = x^2 + xy + yx + y^2 = (x + y) + (xy + yx)$$
hence $xy+yx=0$.

But also, since $yx=-yx$, we have
$$xy-yx=xy + (-yx) = xy+yx =0$$
so $R$ is commutative.

Comment: How did you go from $ 4x^2 $ to 4x in the initial steps?

Comment: Since $x^2=x$, we get
$$4x^2 = x^2+x^2+x^2+x^2 = x + x + x + x = 4x$$

Comment: Thank you! Did you also do this for the third statement?

Comment: Which statement?

Comment: For the line $x^2 $ + xy +yx + $y^2$ = (x+y) + (xy+yx)

Comment: For any expression $u$, we can always replace $u^2$ by $u$.